# onblur to onsubmit not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have this code which works as expected (executes when the user clicks out of the entry field)

```
<input id="sampleID" name="sampleID" type="text" onblur="myfunction(sampleID.value); "/>
```

However I'm having trouble figuring out how to have this work when the user hits the 'enter' button. Ive tried:

```
<input id="sampleID" name="sampleID" type="text" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode==13) myfunction(sampleID.value); "/>
```

but this clears the form input field

Comment: what is the content of `myfunction`? do you have a form with `submit` button? if yes - you will have to prevent the form from submitting, otherwise the `enter` will submit the form.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For instance, post your code on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

`key13` is the <kbd>return/enter</kbd> key. You probably wanted `onblur`s sister event `change`. In order to stop the page from clearing the page, use `preventDefault()`. That will stop the <kbd>ENTER/RETURN</kbd> key from triggering a `submit` event on the `<form>`. The following Snippet demonstrates both.

#### SNIPPET

```js
function test(val) {
  console.log('You have entered: ' + val);
}
```

```html
<form id="f1">
  <label for="testKeyup">Type in box and press the <kbd>ENTER/RETURN</kbd> key</label>
  <input id="testKeyup" name="testKeyup" type="text" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode==13) test(this.value); event.preventDefault()" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="testChange">Type in box and then click anywhere <b>but</b> this box</label>
  <input id="testChange" name="testChange" type="text" onchange="test(this.value);event.preventDefault();" />
</form>
```

Comment: this certainly works as you've depicted it - and thank you for the clarity (I've  voted but don't have enough rep for it to register yet) - but it does not work on my code.. still investigating

Comment: the 'onchange' version works (just as the onblur did) but the onkeyup causes the page refresh

Comment: the onkeyup version does execute the javascript but the page is still reloaded

Comment: Instead of  `onkeyup="if (event.keyCode==13) test(this.value); event.preventDefault()"` try:  `onkeyup="if (event.keyCode==13) test(this.value); return false;"` and/or adding `return false` at the last line of `test()`